# Create React Native module and use it in a React Native project

Tags: android, ios, react-native, npm, npm-install

I would split my big project in two parts:

- UI custom components
- main project

Nice!

I follow [facebook guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup) so:

```
npm install -g react-native-create-library
react-native-create-library foo
cd foo && npm install
cd ../MyBigProject
// Add Foo dependecy
// "foo": "file:../foo"
npm install
```

When I run project I have this error:

> Module 'react' does not exist in the Hast module map

This error refers *foo* module.
Obviously, react is used to create and export custom UI components.

Where I'm wrong?